# Windows explorer monitors directory changes in a tricky way?

Tags: winapi, explorer, readdirectorychangesw

I have a sandbox system redirecting file modifications by hooking Ntxxx file system APIs. An interesting thing is, if i move files in Notepad->File/Open dialog in my sandbox, e.g. from desktop\a.txt to desktop\b\a.txt, the a.txt file on real desktop just disappears, and it comes back after i refresh real desktop by pressing F5. actually there is no change in desktop folder at all, because all changes are directed. I know that most apps use API like ReadDirectoryChanges to monitor changes, but apparently explorer is doing something different. I tried tools like https://directorymonitor.com/, they did not observe any changes on desktop. I guess SHFileOperation internally interact with explorer somehow, but who knows details and how can i prevent this notification? It is really strange for users to see a file disappearing while it is actually still there.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotify

Comment: Not sure I understand what you see. But the Shell also uses https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotify this to get notified of changes. Any folder in the namespace can notify anyone listening to these events that something has changed even if in fact it didn't change. For example, if I notify explorer an item was deleted, it will be removed visually and reappear on next refresh

Comment: But i am not seeing SHChangeNotify called in windbg

Comment: no, i want to know what noficiation explorer receives.

Comment: ok, it is defintely not SHChangeXXX, i blocked all SHChangeNotifyRegister and SHChangeNotifyRegisterThread calls in explorer, but it still disappears!!!

Comment: @herb So you want to filter related notifications to Windows Explorer to prevent file disappearing?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT yes exactly, i dont want file changes in sandbox to affect outside environment

Comment: but i dont want to intercept into explorer, so i need to block it at sender side which is sandboxed app instead of hooking into explorer

Comment: @herb I am wondering why the icon of the file will disappear even if the operation fails which is approved by file's reappearing after refresh the desktop. How and what APIs you redirected to achieve this? Because in general, the file's icon disappears after the move or delete operation successes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows calls windows_storage!SHChangeNotify instead of that one in shell32. Why does Windows have two copies of same API, are they different?